# Having problems filling up my database through an XML file and accesing the data

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, sqlite, cordova

I'm trying to parse a XML file to the SQlite database for my application in phonegap.
The problem I'm encountering seems that my data is not being saved in my database (if I run my code, I'm getting the log: 'Vouchers table: 0 rows found.'.

The code I made is based on the [phonegap API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html) about storage.

Anybody seeing the problem in my code or has some tips how to find my problem?

I tried/checked:

1. The parsing from xml to variables works
2. I tried to get it working with a simplified table, got the same result (none)

**EDIT:** After adding the db.openDatabase, I'm getting a new problem. It seems I'm only inserting my last voucher. Why is this? It seems like he is going through the .each() and rewriting my variables before getting the insert statement done and just get the change to only insert my last statement because that's the one who was last overwriting the variables.

**EDIT2:** After some testing (with the console.log) I have found the source of my problem.
It seems like the success method from my ajax request is not running before the rest of my code. It's running asynchronous I guess .. How do I fix this? I'm thinking of swapping from ajax to JavaScript to parse my XML file. Will this work?

The xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<vouchers>
<voucher>
    <giftID>1</giftID>
    <supplierName>supplierName1</supplierName>
    <title_NL>title_NL1</title_NL>
    <title_FR>title_FR1</title_FR>
    <decr_NL>decr_NL1</decr_NL>
    <decr_FR>decr_FR1</decr_FR>
    <brands_NL>brands_NL1</brands_NL>
    <brands_FR>brands_FR1</brands_FR>
    <exclusion_NL>exclusion_NL1</exclusion_NL>
    <exclusion_FR>exclusion_FR1</exclusion_FR>
    <price_inclBTW>price_inclBTW1</price_inclBTW>
    <serviceFee>serviceFee1</serviceFee>
    <isEvoucher>isEvouche1r</isEvoucher>
    <isFixValidDate>isFixValidDate1</isFixValidDate>
    <Validtxt>Validtx1t</Validtxt>
    <mainAfb>mainAf1</mainAfb>
    <detailAfb1>detailAfb11</detailAfb1>
    <detailAfb2>detailAfb21</detailAfb2>
    <detailAfb3>detailAfb31</detailAfb3>
</voucher>

<voucher>
    <giftID>2</giftID>
    <supplierName>supplierName2</supplierName>
    <title_NL>title_NL2</title_NL>
    <title_FR>title_FR2</title_FR>
    <decr_NL>decr_NL2</decr_NL>
    <decr_FR>decr_FR2</decr_FR>
    <brands_NL>brands_NL2</brands_NL>
    <brands_FR>brands_FR2</brands_FR>
    <exclusion_NL>exclusion_NL2</exclusion_NL>
    <exclusion_FR>exclusion_FR2</exclusion_FR>
    <price_inclBTW>price_inclBTW2</price_inclBTW>
    <serviceFee>serviceFee2</serviceFee>
    <isEvoucher>isEvoucher2</isEvoucher>
    <isFixValidDate>isFixValidDate2</isFixValidDate>
    <Validtxt>Validtxt2</Validtxt>
    <mainAfb>mainAfb2</mainAfb>
    <detailAfb1>detailAfb12</detailAfb1>
    <detailAfb2>detailAfb22</detailAfb2>
    <detailAfb3>detailAfb32</detailAfb3>
</voucher>
</vouchers>
```

The javascript file:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// PhoneGap is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    var db = window.openDatabase("voucher", "1.0", "Voucher database", 1000000);
    db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
}

function populateDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS vouchers');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vouchers (giftID unique, supplierName, title_NL, title_FR, decr_NL, decr_FR, brands_NL, brands_FR, exclusion_NL, exclusion_FR, price_inclBTW, serviceFee, isEvoucher, isFixValidDate, Validtxt, mainAfb, detailAfb1, detailAfb2, detailAfb3)');
}

function errorCB(err) {
    console.log("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
}

// Transaction success callback
//
function successCB() {
    db = window.openDatabase("voucher", "1.0", "Voucher database", 1000000);
    db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);

}

function queryDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT giftID FROM vouchers', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
    }


function querySuccess(tx, results) {
        var len = results.rows.length;
        console.log("Vouchers table: " + len + " rows found.");
        for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
            console.log("Row = " + i + " ID = " + results.rows.item(i).giftID);
        }
    }

function xmlParse() {

db = window.openDatabase("voucher", "1.0", "Voucher database",
 1000000); //**ADDED THIS**

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "testVoucher.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('voucher').each(function() {
                giftID = $(this).find("giftID").text();
                supplierName = $(this).find("supplierName").text();
                title_NL = $(this).find("title_NL").text();
                title_FR = $(this).find("title_FR").text();
                decr_NL = $(this).find("decr_NL").text();
                decr_FR = $(this).find("decr_FR").text();
                brands_NL = $(this).find("title_FR").text();
                brands_FR = $(this).find("title_FR").text();
                exclusion_NL = $(this).find("exclusion_NL").text();
                exclusion_FR = $(this).find("exclusion_FR").text();
                price_inclBTW = $(this).find("price_inclBTW").text();
                serviceFee = $(this).find("serviceFee").text();
                isEvoucher = $(this).find("isEvoucher   ").text();
                isFixValidDate = $(this).find("isFixValidDate").text();
                Validtxt = $(this).find("Validtxt").text();
                mainAfb = $(this).find("mainAfb").text();
                detailAfb1 = $(this).find("detailAfb1").text();
                detailAfb2 = $(this).find("detailAfb2").text();
                detailAfb3 = $(this).find("detailAfb3").text();



                db.transaction(function(tx) {
                    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO vouchers (giftID, supplierName, title_NL, title_FR, decr_NL, decr_FR, brands_NL, brands_FR, exclusion_NL, exclusion_FR, price_inclBTW, serviceFee, isEvoucher, isFixValidDate, Validtxt, mainAfb, detailAfb1, detailAfb2, detailAfb3) VALUES (' + giftID + ',' + supplierName + ',' + title_NL + ',' + title_FR + ',' + decr_NL + ',' + decr_FR + ','
                            + brands_NL + ',' + brands_FR + ',' + exclusion_NL + ',' + exclusion_FR + ',' + price_inclBTW + ',' + serviceFee + ','
                            + isEvoucher + ',' + isFixValidDate + ',' + Validtxt + ',' + mainAfb + ',' + detailAfb1 + ',' + detailAfb2 + ',' + detailAfb3 + ')');

                });
            });
        }

    }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `xmlParse` function `db` is not defined. Before your transaction add this line:

```
db = window.openDatabase("voucher", "1.0", "Voucher database", 1000000);
```

::UPDATED::

Try revising your ajax call like below. I am creating an array of your values and then passing the array to the insert statement:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "testVoucher.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('voucher').each(function() {
                var voucher = [];
                voucher.push($(this).find("giftID").text());
                voucher.push($(this).find("supplierName").text());
                voucher.push($(this).find("title_NL").text());
                voucher.push($(this).find("title_FR").text());
                voucher.push($(this).find("decr_NL").text());
                voucher.push($(this).find("decr_FR").text());
                voucher.push($(this).find("title_FR").text());
                voucher.push($(this).find("title_FR").text());
                voucher.push($(this).find("exclusion_NL").text());
                voucher.push($(this).find("exclusion_FR").text());
                voucher.push($(this).find("price_inclBTW").text());
                voucher.push($(this).find("serviceFee").text());
                voucher.push($(this).find("isEvoucher").text());
                voucher.push($(this).find("isFixValidDate").text());
                voucher.push($(this).find("Validtxt").text());
                voucher.push($(this).find("mainAfb").text());
                voucher.push($(this).find("detailAfb1").text());
                voucher.push($(this).find("detailAfb2").text());
                voucher.push($(this).find("detailAfb3").text());
                console.log(voucher);
                db.transaction(function(tx) {
                    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO vouchers (giftID, supplierName, title_NL, title_FR, decr_NL, decr_FR, brands_NL, brands_FR, exclusion_NL, exclusion_FR, price_inclBTW, serviceFee, isEvoucher, isFixValidDate, Validtxt, mainAfb, detailAfb1, detailAfb2, detailAfb3) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',voucher);
                });
            });
        }

    }
);
```

Comment: Oké, I'm getting 'Vouchers table: 1 rows found. (08:48:10:238)
  at public_html/js/database.js:36
Row = 0 ID = undefined (08:48:10:239)
  at public_html/js/database.js:38' in my log now, so I'm getting closer. Thanks!

Comment: It seems that I'm only adding 1 voucher (the last one I guess) or that my methode is not waiting till my loop is finished before calling the success methode.

Comment: I add a different approach to the insert, and also a console log so you can see each voucher is different as it passes through them. Passing an array to the insert could help if there is a problem with escaping values.

Comment: I already tried parsing it in an array and did the console log as well. The problem is my program running faster than the success methode/insert